# Find usage of methods, attribute, and others in java projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to know if somebody knows how can I find usage of methods, attribute, and other language constructs in Java projects? I've been working with Eclipse AST, but some IDEs still have this stuff implemented. Thus, maybe there is an easiest way than this one.

So I would to find a solution (IDE independent) that I could give a Java project and, for instance, a method declaration, and this solution reports to me the all files and lines that have a call to this method. It is important to highlight other language constructs also are welcome.

Thanks in advance =D

Comment: There is no IDE independent solution. IDEs exist to provide features like this.

Comment: I don't think there is an IDE-independent definition of a "Java project".

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not built-in in the language, therefore if you want it you need either to choose and IDE that provides it (they usually do) or code the specific tool that suits your needs.